# Codeigniter include contact form from contact page inside multiple pages

Tags: php, codeigniter

A codeigniter novice here. I just built a contact page for my codeigniter based website following the [tutorial](https://www.codexworld.com/codeigniter-contact-form-validation-email/) here. It works well. This is the setup:

In the **controller** folder

- Contact.php
- home.php

In the **view** folder

- contact.php
- home.php

The form works well when you visit site.com/contact.
However I will like to add the same contact form on the contact page before the the footer of the home page. So inside controller/home.php, I added the below:

```
public function index()
{           
    $this->load->view('head', $data);
    $this->load->view('home');
    $this->load->view('contact');
    $this->load->view('footer');    
}
```

The homepage then went blank with nothing showing except the caption of the form. Any idea of how this can be properly organized? I want to be able to use the form on multiple pages and not just contact page alone.

Comment: Can you show the output of your view directory?
Also, do you have any errors being printed to your logs?

My first thought is you will want to take the actual contact form out of the contact view, and create a partial. Then include that partial in both the contact view and the home view.

Comment: @Brian. That is exactly what I want to do. Did not get any errors onscreen. Not sure of where the logs are.

Comment: How are you running this application? Are you using nginx or apache? Are you hosting this on  Windows, Mac or Linux?